# Test Fairy Rest API not working

Tags: testfairy

I am trying to call test fairy rest API to get all builds on the account using POSTman but getting missing parameters error.

This is a GET call so parameters are being sent as part of URL

https://app.testfairy.com/api/1/projects?email=abc@gmail.com&api_key=xyzabcdefg

Here is the testfairy guide for the call. Please point out what am I doing wrong here.
https://docs.testfairy.com/API/Rest_API.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send your `email` and `api_key` as Basic Auth `Username` and `password`.
The url will be https://app.testfairy.com/api/1/projects

[image: example using Postman]